# QuickOSM query (in QGIS) appearing in the wrong place. Maybe CRS Problem?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, quickosm

I had a question in [QGIS Buffer distance vs Distance in Distance Matrix](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345322/qgis-buffer-distance-vs-distance-in-distance-matrix)

which in turn made me to change my project CRS from EPSG: 3857 to EPSG: 25832.

My project location is in the middle of Germany (Shown in the image with the green dot, that i added manually)

But then, i queried some data from Quick OSM, only for it to appear somewhere in south of France. (Shown as the red dot)

[image: First query]

At first I realized that the OSMquery layer have a different CRS than my project. (EPSG: 4326), so in turn, I changed the layer CRS from the OSMquery to my Project CRS, which is EPSG: 25832, but then this happened:

[image: query after CRS change]

The red dot (Representing the layer with changed CRS) appears on the sea near the African Continent!

Did I do something wrong? Is there a way to repair this? Is there any command I have to change in the QuickOSM? Or is this a problem with the CRS? Or I just missed a setting somewhere? (Note: I am very new to GIS software in general)

Comment: The layer with the dot has a feature with a geometry (the dot) which have its coordinates in longitude and latitude. E.g, a numer of this order (60 , 30). When you set the layer CRS, the coordinates of the geometry does not change, but changes the interpretation of its coordinates. If you want to reproject the layer to another CRS, you can Export it (with right click) to another CRS instead of set a CRS for the layer.

Comment: Done this, and now it is at least not landing in Africa; but the coordinates from OSMQuery is originally (probably) wrong... That the called data all landed in the South of France..

Comment: I think that the basemap is not being reprojected. QGIS usually costs a lot to reproject to a UTM zone raster layers that exceed the zone. More or less this is how it should look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/itfMQ.jpg

Comment: How did you do that? Sorry for the seemingly dumb question.. Did you use another type of XYZ Tiles? 

I haven't had this problem before because the first time i was working with GIS, it was with Indonesian area, but it is near equator, so the problem with the distance and all was not noticeable. Now other CRS, and these problems appeared.

Comment: My layer is a raster layer with a physical map of the world. My raster layer has its own CRS. When I change the canvas CRS to the UTM zone, the raster layer is being reprojected on the fly to that zone. But QGIS makes a hard use of the CPU for that. I can export the raster to the UTM zone CRS and have it reprojected. But that is not possible with the basemap tiles. You can download a [Natural Earth globe dataset map](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-raster-data/) and use it instead of the basemap.

Comment: Deformations in Mercator projections tend to infinity far away from the central line (the equator in Web Mercator, the central meridian in a UTM zone). In Web Mercator, the map is cutted nearest of latitudes 85 degrees to avoid that, but when you work in a UTM zone you must avoid trying to reproject a layer with the anipodal meridian of the zone. When you try to render it, QGIS needs to deform the layer to infinity and may crash. If you find a raster or vector layer of your work area is much better, reproject it to the zone and work there.

Comment: If not, use Web Mercator for the canvas and use the basemap. But reproject your data layers to the zone (exporting them) before of measure distances in the layer. Once the geometries of the layer in which you are going to work have been reprojected to the UTM zone, you can measure planimetric distances for that layer using its CRS. You can have the basemap tiles and the canvas in Web Mercator, and QGIS will render the layer on the fly on it.